# Question about probability of a singleton in a continuous random variable is zero.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $(\Omega,S,P)$ be a probability space then we have $p({\omega})=0$ ,where $\omega\in\Omega$ that is  $\{\omega\}\subseteq S$.My question is we define a random variable $X\colon\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ then we are saying that $P(\{X=a\}=0$ that is  $P\{X=a\}$=P({$\omega\in \Omega$ such that $X(\omega)=a$})=0,so we are saying that probability of collection of set $\omega$ which maps to a singleton $a$ is zero.My question is that here $a$ is a singleton in $\mathbb{R}$ but the collection of $\omega$ which maps to $a$ might not be a singleton. Then how these two are defining the same thing? I am missing something here.

Comment: Some notes: $\omega \subseteq S$ doesn't make sense because $S$ is a set of _subsets_ of $\Omega$, not elements of $\Omega$.  It would be correct to say $\{\omega\} \in S$.  Second, we don't always have $P(\{\omega\})=0$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$, and we don't always have $P(\{X=a\})=0$. Those are properties of $P$ and $X$ which may or may not hold, and are independent of one another (in the sense that we can have $P(\{\omega\})=0$ for all $\omega \in Omega$ but $P(X=a)>0$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$, and we can have $P(X=a)=0$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$ but $P(\omega)>0$ for some $\omega$.)

Comment: so when we will say that probability of the singleton in a continuous random variable is 0?

Comment: By a continuous RV you probably mean a RV that has a continuous distribution. In other words the distribution function $F(x)=P(X\le x)$ is continuous. This implies that $P(X=x)=0$. At this point (on the level of the distribution of $X$) it does not even matter how $\Omega$ is defined. There could be several proabability spaces $(\Omega,{\cal F},P)$ that model the same distribution $F(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

When you say that the probability of a singleton in a continuous random variable is $0$, I think you are referring to the distribution of that random variable.

More concretely, let $(\Omega,S,P)$ be a probability space, and $X$ be a continuous random variable on that space.  This means $P(\{X=a\}) = 0$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$.  (My first comment was mistaken: this actually does imply $P(\{\omega\}) = 0$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$.)  Now, we define a new probability measure $P_X$ on $\mathbb{R}$ called the *distribution of $X$* by $P_X((a,b)) = P(\{X \in (a,b)\})$ for all $a<b \in \mathbb{R}$.  Then $P_X(\{a\}) = 0$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$, and this property is what I think you are referring to by "the probability of a singleton in a continuous random variable is $0$".

Comment: @Andyale Yes, the set $\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega)=a\}$ may not be a singleton, but when we say that $X$ is a continuous random variable we mean $P(\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega)=a\}) = 0$ for all $a$, regardless of whether that set is a singleton or not.